# Is it possible to have the distance moved by a smartphone by using only the accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

I am trying to have the distance moved by a smartphone to prevent the user for example every 50 cm. Is it possible to do that knowing that I cannot use the step detection because I will put the smartphones in a 4 wheels device and I won't have GPS data because I am doing the experiments indoor.

I have implemented the code to calculate distance using only accelerometer but I figured out that the error is very important and the data of the accelerometer fluctuate a lot.

Can you please help me with that even by some advices or references

Comment: No, those are not precise enough. You could have an acceleration approximation, but this would not be precise enough to calculate a speed. Well, you could have an approximation but I doubt this would be close. I always wanted to find the time to tried to be honest ;) PS : this mostly depends on the component of the device. I did implement once but I had to add a algorithm to smooth the values, that algorith used a parameter that I had to change for every device to get something "usable"

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

The internal sensors of mobile devices are noisy. And to go from an acceleration to a position you have to integrate two times. Then the noise will get too big, hence your position will drift.

There is an [interesting *Google Tech Talks* on this subject](https://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k?t=15m27s) which will explain this subject way better than I would. And even if the video is old, the problem is mainly the maths, and not the hardware, then it's still relevant.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you can't use GPS because device is indoors. You can use Beacons to help you calculate your device's position.
Beacons work using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) to constantly send radio signals. You can calculate distance between your device and each one of Beacons installed based on signal strength and get a location relative to installed Beacons.
This requires some calculations but it may solve your problem.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find many white paper for this topic on many university. For example LRM Team from Poland make some research about this, here you have link [LRM Team Smartphone localization](http://lrm.put.poznan.pl/smartphone-localization/). But for effective localization you need use all of smarthphone sensor.